Could not load type 'Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Services.EntityService`1' - Upgrade to 10.3.1
Upgrade from 9.1.1 to 10.3.1
Full error:

Could not load type 'Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Services.EntityService`1' from assembly 'Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Already upgraded the assembly in the Nuget manager and published already. However, still getting the same error. When I check the bin folder, the assembly version is still 9.0.0.
Any help? Thanks

After Sitecore 9.3, EntityService has been moved from Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore dll. Now the class should be derived from below class inside Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure dll to use entity service.
Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Services.EntityServiceBase

You will need to derive from above abstract class in your solution and then deploy to the website.
Note: Version 9.0 coming inside the bin folder is correct, nothing to be changed there.
More details on the same can be found here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/create-an-entityservice.html#create-an-entityservice-1
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thank you ckhanna!
